# Unable to connect to remote MySQL Server in Digital Ocean

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to a remote MySQL server 5.7 installed on Ubuntu 16.04 from my workstation.

Here is the error i am getting (Using Navicat to connect).

[image]

To make it work I followed the following steps.

1) `GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO user@xx.xxx.xx.xx IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password'`;

2) `flush privileges;`

3) `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart`

Some forums recommends commenting line starts with "bind-address" on `my.cnf` which resides in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. The problem is there is no such line on my installation.

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

I also tried to open ports on firewall using the following commands.

```
sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp
sudo service ufw restart
```

But still stuck with the same problem.

**Update:** To make MySQL to listen to all interfaces i added 
`bind-address=0.0.0.0` to `my.cnf` file. Now MySQL is not even restarting and throws the following error.

```
demo@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
[....] Restarting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
demo@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Opening up the port on the firewall solved the problem for me. DigitalOcean must lock it down by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following ways to debugging this-

First you need to understands what the logs says- the default logs in ubuntu is stores in /var/log/mysql folder or go to mentioned location in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Second if you want to access your mysql server from any where location then just comment the line by putting # at starting. So please conmment the bind-address line. It will now access from any where.

```
[mysqld]
# bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Start the mysql server and use telnet from client system with the ip & port. Check are you able to connect or not. for ex-

```
telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 3306
```

If you are able to connect then create user in mysql server, where I used % in hostname which means it can be connect from any client For ex-

```
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

If still its showing errors then you need to post the logs.

Answer (score 0):

about adding `bind-address=0.0.0.0` to /etc/mysql/my.cnf, make sure you actually add 2 lines:

> [mysqld]
>
> bind-address=0.0.0.0

This will solve the error in your "Update" paragraph, and hopefully the whole scenario will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. and fixed myself.

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

it means you should check conf.d and mysql.conf.d folder.
there will be conf files.
so, you can change bind-address in the real conf file.